# How to share a ordering between two lists in Python

Tags: python, pandas, list

i got a list of ids and a lists of dates. Both are single entries of separate pandas dataframe columns. Each date corresponds to an id. Something like:

```
[852634, 727417, 881231]   [2018-05-29, 2015-11-23, 2019-06-26]
```

How can i order the dates (ascending or descending, does not matter) and export the same ordering to the IDs?

The wanted result is:

```
[727417, 852634, 881231]   [ 2015-11-23, 2018-05-29, 2019-06-26]
```

Thank you in advance for all the suggestions,
Alessandro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zip...

```
>>> x = [852634, 727417, 881231]
>>> y = ["2018-05-29", "2015-11-23", "2019-06-26"]
>>> list(zip(y, x))
[('2018-05-29', 852634), ('2015-11-23', 727417), ('2019-06-26', 881231)]
```

sort...

```
>>> sorted(zip(y,x))
[('2015-11-23', 727417), ('2018-05-29', 852634), ('2019-06-26', 881231)]
```

and unzip.

```
>>> [x for _, x in sorted(zip(y,x))]
[727417, 852634, 881231]
```

This is an example of a general technique called a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform). You decorate the list of IDs you want to sort with the corresponding dates, sort the decorated list, then extract (undecorated) the original values from the result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and expecially for the general definition.

Answer (score 2):

Use numpy -

```
l1_key = np.argsort(l1)

l1_sorted = np.array(l1)[l1_key]
l2_sorted = np.array(l2)[l1_key]
```

**Output**

```
print(l1_sorted)
print(l2_sorted)

[727417 852634 881231]
['2015-11-23' '2018-05-29' '2019-06-26']
```

Comment: Very pythonic one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a dataframe, it's probably much easier to `.explode()` 'em and `.sort_values()` there before export!

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"ids": [[852634, 727417, 881231], [90,100,110,115]], "dates": [["2018-05-29", "2015-11-23", "2019-06-26"], ["2015-01-01", "2021-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2021-01-01"]]})
>>> df
                        ids                                             dates
0  [852634, 727417, 881231]              [2018-05-29, 2015-11-23, 2019-06-26]
1       [90, 100, 110, 115]  [2015-01-01, 2021-01-01, 2020-01-01, 2021-01-01]
>>> df.explode(["ids", "dates"]).sort_values("dates")
      ids       dates
1      90  2015-01-01
0  727417  2015-11-23
0  852634  2018-05-29
0  881231  2019-06-26
1     110  2020-01-01
1     100  2021-01-01
1     115  2021-01-01
>>> df.explode(["ids", "dates"]).sort_values("dates")["ids"].to_numpy()
array([90, 727417, 852634, 881231, 110, 100, 115], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Got your point, but those lists are coming from a previous grouby: the group_by operation will maintain the ordering?

Comment: hmm.. well, they'll be ordered by the groupby's ordering .. however, is there actually a need to do so or are the IDs already mapped beforehand? were there native lists before using groupby?

Answer (score 0):

you can do `list.sort()` for the int

```
ids = ids.sort()
```

and you could use datetime to do the sortedlist:

```
from datetime import datetime
dates = ["2018-05-29", "2015-11-23", "2019-06-26"]
dates = [datetime.strptime(date,"%Y-%M-%d") for date in dates]
dates.sort()
print(dates)
```

so the code becomes:

```
from datetime import datetime
ids = [852634, 727417, 881231]
dates = ["2018-05-29", "2015-11-23", "2019-06-26"]
print("Before: ",ids,dates)
ids = ids.sort()
dates = [datetime.strptime(date,"%Y-%M-%d") for date in dates]
dates.sort()
print("After: ",ids,dates)
```

Comment: The IDs list has to inherit the same ordering of the dates list. Are you sure this would do the trick?